# Conditional move ошибка x86-16

Tags: ассемблер, x86

Возникает ошибка при трансляции под DOS следующего сегмента кода:

```
60 cmp ah, al   ;\ Кладём меньшее
61 cmovb ah, al ;/ значение
```

Ошибка следующая:

> lr3.ASM(61): error A2105: Expected: instruction, directive, or label

Предварительно внутри ah, al, находятся db. Подскажите причину ошибки и её возможное исправление

Comment: `cmovb` не входит в набор команд .8086

Comment: Благодарю, не находил по этому инфу, а какой набор надо подключить?

Comment: посмотрите параметры запуска вашего ассемблера. если не ошибаюсь команда появилась на 486 процессорах, надо где то указать что у вас не ниже. или может в коде надо какую нибудь директиву (типа `.i586`)для этого написать. но это всецело зависит от используемого ассемблера, а его вы в вопросе не указали. Кстати старые DOS версии ассемблеров часто таких команд не знали в принципе

Comment: Замените на работающее для любого набора `cmp ah,al` `jbe $+2` `mov ah,al`